# Sound playing over same sound with SoundPool Android

Tags: java, android, soundpool

When I click on my `ImageButton` it plays the sound through `SoundPool` perfectly, but when I click on it again while that sound is playing - it will play that sound again, but over it.

Is there any way to make it not play over the sound? In other terms make it not overlap with the other sound?

Here's my method that I'm calling

```
public void playSound(String sound)
{
    int path = getResources().getIdentifier(sound, "raw", getPackageName());


    int MAX_STREAMS = 1;
    SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int soundId, int status) {
            int loop = 0;
            int priority = 0;
            float rate = 1.f;
            soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, priority, loop, rate);
        }
    });
    soundPool.load(this, path, 1);

    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
```

Comment: Create and set up your `SoundPool` elsewhere. Then, inside `playSound` call `stop` on the `SoundPool` with the streamID from a previous call to `play` (if `play` has been called previously), and then call `play`.

Comment: So I'll declare the SoundPool at the top of my java class correct? Sorry, I'm new to android development.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `private static SoundPool pool;` before `onCreate` .

Then in your function ,check not null and release that instance. Basically have one instance of soundpool instead of creating one everytime `playSound()` is called

```
if(pool!=null)
pool.release()
else
pool = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

then play.